# How to compile objdump for the m32c architecture

Tags: embedded, disassembly, objdump

I would like to use objdump to view binary m32c files.  When I type in: `objdump -i` the architecture list returned is i386 based.  Looking at the source code from binutils it appears that the m32c architecture is supported, just not compiled in by default.

I've also seen `arm-none-eabi-objdump` for the embedded ARM market.  What I would like to create is a compiled version of objdump for the m32c architecture.  Has anyone done something similar?

Comment: Windows or Linux hosted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building binutils for a specific target is pretty straightforward.  If binutils is to be hosted on Windows, you will need to install MinGW/GCC and the Msys shell environment.  Then from within a Linux bash shell or msys on Windows:

1. Create a directory to build the tools ()
2. Create a directory to which to install the tools ()
3. Extract the binutils package into , hereafter  refers to the binutils verion you are building, and is indicated in the package name (binutils-.tar.bz2)
4. Working from , configure the package for the appropriate target and host:

`../binutils-<version>/configure --target m32c-elf --prefix <installdir>`

In Windows you can also add to the configure command line  `--enable-win32-registry=gnu_m32c` to allow path lookup via the registry.  The toolchain name `gnu_m32c` is arbitrary - you can call it what you like.

5. Run `make` to build the tools.
6. Run `make install-strip` to install the tools.

---

**Note:**

If you are installing on Windows and used the `--enable-win32-registry` option but subsequently choose to move the installation, or are installing your pre-build tools on a new host, you will need to modify the registry to match; this can be done in regedit editing the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Free Software Foundation\gnu_m32c`, adding/modifying the item:`"BINUTILS"="<installdir>"`  if you have installed GCC as well there are related keys:

```
"GCC"="<gccinstalldir>"
"G++"="<gppinstalldir>"
```